# Proving that for any odd integer: $\lceil \frac{N^2}{4} \rceil = \frac{N^2 + 3}{4}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm trying to construct a proof that for any odd integer: the ceiling of $\large \lceil  \frac{N^2}{4} \rceil = \frac{N^2 + 3}{4}$.

Anyone have a second to show me how this is done?  Thanks!

Comment: Pleas do not deface your questions. This devalues the good answers it has received.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  what is $N^2 \pmod 4$ for odd $N$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $N=2k+1$. Then the LHS term is.... The RHS term is.... Hence they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Take $N=2k+1$ then we have,
$(N^2+3)/4=k^2+k+1$

$N^2/4=k^2+k+1/4,\Rightarrow $ its ceiling is $\lceil N^2/4\rceil =k^2+k+1=(N^2+3)/4$